# CSS-sprites alternative in html source

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to set the source of a `<img>` tag in HTML source to a partial image from a bigger image? I know I can do this in CSS with something like: `background-position: 0px -76px;` but how can I do this for `<img>` and `<input type="image">`?

EDIT: Screenshot from Chrome:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `<img src` to a partial image from a bigger image? There is no way.

You already have the answer: use the `background` CSS property and position it to the desired coordinates. Note: You *can* assign background images to the `<img>` tag if that helps you at all.

Just for kicks, as an alternate solution: You could append your image with a query string that contains the coordinates and size:

```
<img src="/my_image.jpg?x=400&y=220&width=200&height=120">
```

...then use `.htaccess` to send this request to a server side script that processes the image and outputs the partial image (but that's another topic altogether).

This post might help you with the `.htaccess` bit, should you choose to implement it:

- [RewriteRule for image file requests only if a query string is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276348/rewriterule-for-image-file-requests-only-if-a-query-string-is-present)

It really sounds like you want to use CSS sprites, there are a number of tutorials on this, here's one:

- http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: Thanks. But there's one little problem here, I have a problem like the one in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108983/input-type-image-shows-unwanted-border-in-chrome-and-broken-link-in-ie7). I want to create a search box with a submit button of type image. When I set the `src=""`, a border will be shown in IE and Chrome (not FF). At the same type I want to put all my images in one big image and use offsets. What should I do?

Comment: You should not use `<input type="image">`, it's actually designed for another purpose (like image maps, where the coordinates clicked have importance). Use CSS to style a `<button type="submit">` instead. You can even just toss an `<img>` into a `<button>`, or simply style a `<input type="submit">` (but button is more flexible). You really are asking how to use image sprites.

Comment: I'm actually using CSS sprites. I just didn't know the name :D Thanks. I'll change the title of my question. I've used the `border:0` (or `none`). It will not work if `src=""`.

Comment: I don't know. That's the thing. I think when I set `src=""` the browser (IE and Chrome) looks for the image and if haven't found, they show an error image or an empty image with borders. So I have to put something in there. If I slice the image and put the address in the `src` it will fix it but I want to avoid the HTTP request.

Comment: Is there some compelling reason why you must use `src` and `type="image"` instead of CSS?

Comment: I've added an screenshot from chrome to the question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6515/discussion-between-alireza-noori-and-madmartigan)

Answer (score 0):

Simply put you cant unless you scale the image down or up.

Use an outer span with `overflow:hidden` and set the size of the image on that.

Something like

```
span.thumb
{  
width:120px;
height:70px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Put the image inside this `span`

Answer (score 0):

you would probably have to wrap it in a `<div>` that is smaller than the `<img>` and then set the offset of the image with `top:y;`  or `margin-top: y;`